# Twisted python not serving file when connecting to the server using public IP address

Tags: python, twisted

I'm working on Python with the Twisted modules.
I have the following code

```
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.static import File

root = File("test")
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(80, factory)
reactor.run()
```

There is an index.html file within the test directory on the same folder as the python file.

This is the problem: When I load up  'localhost' on the browser, the index.html page gets displayed correctly. However, when I try loading the page using my public IP address, say http://218.248.xxx.180/, the browser waits for a long time and then throws up an error message showing the page is taking too long to respond.

My internet is working fine, (I'm posting this question using the same). I also checked my IP address using http://whatismyip.com, and other sources.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate ports forwarded in your router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Like Broseph pointed out, I didn't have the port forwarded out in the router. Thank you for engaging.